# Getting the selected value of a radio button mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

How do I get the value from the below radio buttons and assign it to a property in my model?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AccountContacts)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("AccountContact", item) @item
}
```

Thanks

Dan

Comment: This is how I have written within one of our project: @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectedAnswer, item.Id) @item.AnswerText Model.AccountContacts.FirstOrDefault().SelectedAnswer;

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the value from the below radio buttons and assign it to a property in my model?

In first case, you have to just add in your controller method `string item`, like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Blahblah(string item)
{ 
  ... 
}
```

Optionally, you could use `Request.Form` value. Like here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Blahblah()
{ 
    var yourItem = Request.Form["item"];
    ...
}
```

If you want to use model for that case, you should have:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedItem, item)
```

then, in your model:

```
public int SelectedItem{ get; set; }
```

and at least in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Blahblah(SomeModel model)
{ 
  var item = model.SelectedItem;
  ... 
}
```